# Characteristic of rings and a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So the question is:

$f:R \to R'$ is a homomorphism of rings with unity such that $f(1_R)=1_{R'}$. Show that if $R'$ has characteristic $0$ then so does $R$.

How I tried proving this is by:
$$(1_{R'}+...+1_{R'}) \neq 0_{R'} $$
$$f(1_R)+...+f(1_R) \neq 0_{R'}$$
$$f(1_R+...+1_R) \neq 0_{R'}$$
$$f(n \times 1_R) \neq f(0_R)$$

What I need to show is that: 
$$n \times 1_R \neq 0_R$$
I feel like I'm on the right track but missing the last step. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $n1_R=0, n\neq 0, f(n1_R)=nf(1_R)=n1_{R'}=0$ contradiction since the characteristic of $R'$ is zero.

Comment: Wow, much simpler solution than what I tried!